# How do I store information in a method so I can use it in a different method later?

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement

I am very new to Java, so sorry if this is stupid and obvious or worded poorly. I don't really know enough yet to know what I don't know.

So I decided that since I have to learn Java, I'd just jump in head first and try to figure it out as I go. So far, it's worked decently. I'm trying to reinforce some basic concepts I already know by writing small programs that do trivial stuff.

I decided I'd write a little text based adventure game and it's working well so far. I'm using Scanners and Switches to call methods that use Scanners and Switches to call other methods. That's all working fine.

So far it's a very linear straight line, like an old choose your own adventure book. But, I wanted to add a player inventory. I have a very vague idea of how to do it, but I have a pretty solid idea of what I want it to do.

So, basically I want to store a piece of information that says the player has a specific item. I want to be able to test for the presence of more than one item at once. And I want to be able to tell the player what items he has at any point in the game.

I don't really know how to ask the question better.

My best guess is doing something like

```
int key, potion;
key = 0
potion = 2
```

and then testing the values of each one

```
if (key = 0) {
System.out.println("you don't have the key ");
}
if (key > 0) {
System.out.prinln("You unlock the door");
}
```

I'm doing each new room as a separate method, so the whole game is just a big chain of methods. So my hope is that the information about items can be stored in a separate method that I can access through switches or if/else in the current room method the player is in. So, the player is unlocking a door in room2, which is its own method, and he picked up the key in room1, which is its own method, and the key is stored as an integer in the inventory method. But the key was one use, so the key integer is set to 0 and the method room3 starts. If that makes any sense.

Again, sorry if this is really stupid basic stuff. I'm very new to programming.

Comment: What you want is called an "instance variable".

Comment: Java is Object oriented programming. What you are trying to do with methods, try to do with classes & objects. May be room as class which will store key & position and create objects for different rooms. I haven’t understood your question or game but try to look at it from class & objects rather than methods.

Comment: Sorry - but please understand that this is not programming school that teaches you stuff that you can find on page 2 of any decent book on Java. You are supposed to do serious research prior posting questions here. The term you want to search for is "instance variable" - also known as fields of a class.

Answer (score 0):

No problem and I applaud you for choosing to learn programming.  This is basic data structures.  If you want to hold a value, in most programming languages, you'll have an array.  I think breaking your logic down is a good idea i.e., (store an item, test for > 1, list items).  The first step is making this as simple as possible and than maybe adding getters/setters later through refactors.  Ultimately, your goal is to make the most basic code work first (like this) and than refactoring towards an object oriented class with getters/setters and/or a HashMap.

1:

```
public class PlayerInventory
{
    private String[] inventoryStr = new String[20]; // basic implementation

inventoryStr[0] = "Phone";
inventoryStr[0] = "Book";
}
```

2:

```
int arrayLength = inventoryStr.length;
```

3:

```
for(int i=0; i < inventoryStr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println( inventoryStr[i] );
}
```

Refactor (after you write unit tests for this)

1*: (with a list)

```
    import java.util.*;  
    import java.util.*;  

    public class CollectionGetterSetter {  
        private List<String> playerInventory;  

        public void setPlayerInventory(List<String> inv) {  
            this.playerInventory = inv;  
        }  

        public List<String> getPlayerInventory() {  
            return this.playerInventory;  
        }  

        public static void main(String[] args) {  
            CollectionGetterSetter app = new CollectionGetterSetter();  
            List<String> PlayerInventory = new ArrayList();  
            PlayerInventory.add("phone");  
            PlayerInventory.add("book");  
            PlayerInventory.add("glasses");  
            PlayerInventory.add("nav");  

            app.setPlayerInventory(PlayerInventory);  

            System.out.println("Player 1: " + PlayerInventory);    

            List<String> PlayerInventory2 = new ArrayList();  
            PlayerInventory2.add("cap");  
            PlayerInventory2.add("gown");  
            PlayerInventory2.add("foo");  
            PlayerInventory2.add("bar");  

        }  

    }
```